# Parsing Pandas Series From Another Series

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to parse a series of text, using a series of numbers like the code below, but all i get in return is a series of NaN's.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
numData = np.array([4,6,4,3,6])
txtData = np.array(['bluebox','yellowbox','greybox','redbox','orangebox'])
n = pd.Series(numData)
t = pd.Series(txtData)
x = t.str[:n]
print (x)
```

output is

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

I would like the output to be

```
0      blue
1    yellow
2      grey
3       red
4    orange
```

Is there an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple list comprehension if in reality you can't chop off the last 3 characters and need to rely on your slice ranges. You will need error handling if your data aren't guaranteed to be all strings, or if `end` can exceed the length of the string.

```
pd.Series([x[:end] for x,end in zip(t,n)], index=t.index)

0      blue
1    yellow
2      grey
3       red
4    orange
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`pd.Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
t.str.slice(stop=-3)
# short hand for this is t.str[:-3]
0      blue
1    yellow
2      grey
3       red
4    orange
dtype: object
```

Or cast `numData` as an *iterator* using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)

```
it = iter(numData)
t.map(lambda x:x[slice(next(it))])
0      blue
1    yellow
2      grey
3       red
4    orange
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
numdata_iter = iter(numData)
x = t.apply(lambda text: text[:next(numdata_iter)])
```

We turn the `numData` into an iterator and then invoke `next` on it for each slicing in `apply`.